# Uninstall MySQL without removing HHVM on Laravel Forge

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, hhvm, laravel-forge

Since I maintain database and web servers separatly, I wanted to have my Forge's maintained web server without mysql, as it tend to use a *lot* of memory, even if I don't use it.

Trying to run a `sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-client mysql-server mysql-common` will result in the following output:

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Package 'mysql-server' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ghostscript gsfonts imagemagick-common libaio1 libavahi-client3
  libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libboost-context1.54.0
  libboost-filesystem1.54.0 libboost-program-options1.54.0
  libboost-regex1.54.0 libboost-system1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0 libcups2
  libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libdbi-perl libfftw3-double3 libgflags2
  libgoogle-glog0 libgs9 libgs9-common libijs-0.35 libjasper1 libjbig2dec0
  libjemalloc1 liblcms2-2 liblqr-1-0 libmagickcore5 libmagickwand5
  libmemcached10 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libtbb2 libterm-readkey-perl
  libunwind8 linux-headers-3.13.0-52 linux-headers-3.13.0-52-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic
  mysql-client-core-5.6 mysql-server-core-5.6 poppler-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  hhvm libdbd-mysql-perl libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.6 mysql-common
  mysql-common-5.6 mysql-server-5.6
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 7 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
After this operation, 113 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.`

As you can see, I ask for the removal of mysql, but it'll also remove `hhvm` which I want to keep! Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This may be better posted on http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AndyJoiner that's true. What is the best course of action? Delete this questions and post it over there or is there a way to properly move it?

Comment: "If you notice that you posted on the wrong site, just delete your question and post on the correct site" - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5754/178156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HHVM's mysql client and other mysql functionality (which you almost certainly want) relies on the mysql client libraries, which you are trying to remove. `sudo apt-get remove mysql-server` should work and remove the mysql server while leaving the client libraries that HHVM needs intact.

Comment: Actually, it says that mysql-server is not installed.

Comment: Actually, never mind, it's just that the package installed was "mysql-server-5.6". Silly me!